# problem with posix timer

Tags: kernel

Using posix timers in SIGEV_THREAD mode. I set the itimerspec.it_value and itimerspec.it_interval with appropriate values and call timer_settime to start the timer. This works as expected. I now want to disable the timer so I set all values in the itemerspec structure to zero. Calling timer_settime again I expect the timer to stop, but it does not. I see complaints about this going back over a decade. Does this actually work? If not will this ever be fixed?